# Swagger and Spring MVC integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

when integrate swagger with mvc and use java-based configuration like

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    .
    .
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

and use url `http://localhost:8080/admin-api/admin/swagger-ui.html` it give 404.
when i remove `addResourceHandlers` from `SwaggerConfig`  configuration class and configure through xml like

```
<mvc:resources mapping="swagger-ui.html" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/" />
```

with the same url `http://localhost:8080/admin-api/admin/swagger-ui.html` it run without problems. how can i use java-based configuration?

Comment: can u able to give swagger's   @API

Answer (score 0):

In swagger - java based configuration
a class exteds from WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, in that class file by override **addResourceHandlers**  like below

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try flagging your `SwaggerConfig` with [@EnableWebMvc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/EnableWebMvc.html) and register `"**/**"` as another ResourceHandler, as follows:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("**/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}
```

Also have a look at [Docket](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/javadoc/2.6.0/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/Docket.html), here is the link for the sample application using Docket API- [swagger-example](https://github.com/arpitaggarwal/swagger-example).